# How do I set up a PHP Class to read from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, multidimensional-array

I need some outside help on this in order to figure it out if I'm ever going to understand how to do this...

I have a multidimensional array that I am trying to set up an class for so I can use it as an object, so that I can call parts of it dynamically.

Here's a small snippet of my array so you can see the structure I'm working with.

```
<?php $modelMap=array(
    'RM3H3FEW' => array('year' => 2015,
                        'model' => 'CR-V',
                        'trim_level'=>array('LX','lx2wd'), 
                        'transmission' => '2WD Continuously Variable ',
                        'colors' => array( 
                                        'BK' => 'Crystal Black Pearl',
                                        'BL' => 'Obsidian Blue Pearl',
                                        'CS' => 'Copper Sunset Pearl',
                                        'KC' => 'Kona Coffee Metallic',
                                        'MA' => 'Mountain Air Metallic',
                                        'MS' => 'Modern Steel Metallic',
                                        'RE' => 'Basque Red Pearl II',
                                        'SI' => 'Alabaster Silver Metallic',
                                        'UT' => 'Urban Titanium Metallic',
                                        'WH' => 'White Diamond Pearl',
                                        )
                        ),
    'RM4H3FEW' => array('year' => 2015,
                        'model' => 'CR-V',
                        'trim_level'=>array('LX','lxawd'),
                        'transmission' => 'AWD Continuously Variable ',
                        'colors' => array( 
                                        'BK' => 'Crystal Black Pearl',
                                        'BL' => 'Obsidian Blue Pearl',
                                        'CS' => 'Copper Sunset Pearl',
                                        'KC' => 'Kona Coffee Metallic',
                                        'MA' => 'Mountain Air Metallic',
                                        'MS' => 'Modern Steel Metallic',
                                        'RE' => 'Basque Red Pearl II',
                                        'SI' => 'Alabaster Silver Metallic',
                                        'UT' => 'Urban Titanium Metallic',
                                        'WH' => 'White Diamond Pearl',
                                        )
                        );
?>
```

And here is the Class I'm trying to build in order to make this an object. Needless to say, I haven't got very far...

```
 <?php
            class OptionsBuild
            {
                public $year = 0;
                public $model = '';
                public $transmission = '';
                public $trimlevel = '';
                public $colorID = '';
                public $colorName = '';

                public function __construct($modelMap)
                {

                    $this->transmission = $transmission;
                    $this->trimlevel = $trimlevel;
                    $this->colorID = $colorID;
                    $this->colorName = $colorName;

                }

            }

            //Test area
            $obj = new OptionsBuild;

            $obj = __construct($modelMap);


            ?>
```

Also I keep getting an error, whenever I try to create a function that does anything, telling me my function doesn't exist and acting like it isn't there. Why is this?

To summarize, I'm just trying to set up a class that will allow me to enter my multidimensional array, and then set it up so that I can add functions/methods to get year, model, trim-level, transmission, and colors. Is this even possible? Please be kind if this is a simple solution, I am new to PHP, new to programming, and am trying to create my very first object/class.

Answer (score 1):

Construct is a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) it is automatically called when you make a new class

Remove the call to __construct and pass $modelMap in the new call

```
        $obj = new OptionsBuild($modelMap);
```

Second I don't really know what you are trying to do with your object but are you wanting to make several objects for each key in the array? e.g. RM4H3FEW is a seperate object from RM3H3FEW?

If that is the case you will to create them in a loop e.g.

```
foreach ($modelMap as $model) {
    $obj = new OptionsBuild($model);
}
```

Let me know intended use and I can help more...

Comment: Thanks for the response! and yes, I have over 1000 model codes (eg RM4H3FEW) that are in the multidimensional array format. 

And just like you said, the goal is to have each model number (aka each vehicle) as a separate object... I think.

My idea was to run a foreach loop that will make each modelcode(eg RM4H3FEW) as a seperate object and from there I want to be able to call up individual stats (eg year, model) for each modelcode. 

Im going to try working with the foreach example you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to solve a problem using complicated arrays and objects, when a sound use of objects is probably what you want. You can handle this nicely with object oriented principles. Multidimensional arrays are a hassle, and generally hard to keep track of and use. Using objects is often a good way to get rid of them.

Also, you are having technical problems because you are accessing variables incorrectly. For example, you have not created the "code" field, which $this->code would refer to. $this refers to the object itself, and whatever comes after the -> is what part of the object you want to access. In your case, $this->year references the year-value stored in the OptionsBuild object that the expression is written inside.

Given that, here is how I would structure the code you presented us, given how I imagine you want it to work. Hope it makes sense.

The OptionsBuild object is defined like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * User: hjorthjort
 * Date: 15-06-21
 * Time: 02:40
 */

    class OptionsBuild {
        public $year = 0;
        public $model = '';
        public $transmission = '';
        public $trimlevel = '';
        public $colorID = '';
        public $colorName = '';

        private static $colors = array( //This will always be the same, so make it a static field.
            'BK' => 'Crystal Black Pearl',
            'BL' => 'Obsidian Blue Pearl',
            'CS' => 'Copper Sunset Pearl',
            'KC' => 'Kona Coffee Metallic',
            'MA' => 'Mountain Air Metallic',
            'MS' => 'Modern Steel Metallic',
            'RE' => 'Basque Red Pearl II',
            'SI' => 'Alabaster Silver Metallic',
            'UT' => 'Urban Titanium Metallic',
            'WH' => 'White Diamond Pearl',
        );

        public function __construct($modelMap)
        {
            $this->year = $modelMap['year'];
            $this->model = $modelMap['model'];

            $this->transmission = $modelMap['transmission'];
            $this->trimlevel = $modelMap['trim_level'];
            $this->colorID = $modelMap['colorID'];

            $this->colorName = OptionsBuild::$colors[$this->colorID];
        }

    }
```

And the modelMap-arrays are then made like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * User: hjorthjort
 * Date: 15-06-21
 * Time: 02:38
 */

$modelMap1 = array('year' => 2015,
    'model' => 'CR-V',
    'trim_level'=>array('LX','lx2wd'),
    'transmission' => '2WD Continuously Variable ',
    'colorID' => 'BK'
);

$modelMap2 = array('year' => 2015,
    'model' => 'CR-V',
    'trim_level'=>array('LX','lxawd'),
    'transmission' => 'AWD Continuously Variable ',
    'colorID' => 'CS'
);

include_once('OptionsBuild.php');

$obj1 = new OptionsBuild($modelMap1);
$obj2 = new OptionsBuild($modelMap2);

$objects = array('RM3H3FEW' => $obj1, 'RM4H3FEW' => $obj2);

print_r($objects); //To see what you have created thus far.
```

Note how a new OptionsBuild is created using the "new" keyword, not by calling __construct (even though using "new" does exactly what I imagine you wanted to achieve by calling __construct).

Here is the output from print_r. The $objects array now holds two objects, identified by the same strings you used at the top level. Each object then in turn contains information about year, transmission, etc.

```
    Array
(
[RM3H3FEW] => OptionsBuild Object
    (
        [year] => 2015
        [model] => CR-V
        [transmission] => 2WD Continuously Variable 
        [trimlevel] => Array
            (
                [0] => LX
                [1] => lx2wd
            )

        [colorID] => BK
        [colorName] => Crystal Black Pearl
    )

[RM4H3FEW] => OptionsBuild Object
    (
        [year] => 2015
        [model] => CR-V
        [transmission] => AWD Continuously Variable 
        [trimlevel] => Array
            (
                [0] => LX
                [1] => lxawd
            )

        [colorID] => CS
        [colorName] => Copper Sunset Pearl
    )

)
```

Also note how the array is accessed above – by the array name, angle brackets [] and the name of the key, like

```
 $modelMap['transmission']
```

So to get the first object in the array, RM3H3FEW, and its attributes, you would write

```
 $variable = $objects['RM3H3FEW']; //Get the object
 $variable = $objects['RM3H3FEW'][year]; //Get the year of the object
 $variable = $objects['RM3H3FEW']['trimlevel'][1] //Get lx2wd (not sure what that is)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I found 3 issues.

1. It appears that you're converting a ModelMap array to a single OptionsBuild class; in reality, you want to create an array of classes.
2. You are storing a single color and trimlevel, whereas you want to store an array of them.
3. Additionally, you are using the magic method `__construct` improperly. It is executed when the object is initialized using `New Object($argumentsForConstruct)`.

Try changing your "test area" to this:

```
$models = Array()
foreach ($modelMap as $modelArray) {
    $models[] = New OptionsBuild($modelMap)
}
```

The looping over the array and appending to another array solves issue 1, and the `New` syntax fixes issue 3. For issue 2, change the initial values of array properties to `Array()` instead of `''`.

Finally, you need to update your `__construct` to `$this->var = $array["var"]`, which will set properties based on the corresponding keys in the input array.

```
public function __construct($modelMap) {
    $this->year = $modelMap["year"]
    $this->model = $modelMap["model"]
    $this->trimlevel = $modelMap["trim_level"]
    //Continue for the rest of your properties
}
```

Hopefully this lets you convert from array to a PHP OOP object.

Answer (score 0):

line:
   $obj = __construct($modelMap);

is wrong, constructors are self called when they objects are created:

for your example it should be liek:

```
$obj = new OptionsBuild($modelMap);
```